# How to get the screen x-positions of an XYSeries x-positions?

Tags: android, achartengine

Let's say I have this [`XYSeries`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html):

```
XYSeries temps = new XYSeries("Temperature");
temps.add(0, 43);
temps.add(1, 42);
temps.add(2, 40);
temps.add(3, 38);
temps.add(4, 35);
temps.add(5, 35);
temps.add(6, 34);
temps.add(7, 33);
temps.add(8, 32);
temps.add(9, 32);
```

If rendered, this would chart the temperature over a 10 hour period.

How can I get the screen x-position for each of the data points in this series? In other words, how would I find out where the 6th data point lies onscreen?

What I'm trying to do is determine which data point is nearest -- on the x-axis -- to the location of where the user touches the screen so that details on the data point can be displayed.

[`XYChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate()`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/XYChart.html#getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate%28org.achartengine.model.Point%29) sort of works except the user must touch a line directly, whereas they should be able to touch anywhere vertically on that data point's x-axis.

I would think it's a matter of simply converting the chart space to screen space (or vice versa), but I have not seen any methods in the Javadoc that take only an x-position; they all require both an x and y, and if the y doesn't match the data point then nothing gets returned.

Any ideas?

**Update**:

Taking Dan's wisdom into account, you can get the "chart space" x-position of a given screen x-position with the `toScreenPoint()` method, as follows:

```
double[] chartPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] {event.getX(), event.getY()}, 2);
// double[0] == 4935.436905570652
```

However, now the problem is taking this coordinate and finding the data point it is nearest. I could manually search for the nearest data point myself if there was a way to get the "chart space" x-position for a given XYSeries index/datapoint:

```
// Build a list of the data points' chart space x-positions
double[] dataPointPositions = new double[temps.getItemCount()];
for(int index = 0; index < dataPointPositions.length; index++)
{
    dataPointPositions[index] = getXPositionForIndex(index, scale);
}

// (Go thru the list of data point positions, comparing them to the
// value taken from toScreenPoint() to find which one is closest.)
```

So the million dollar question now becomes, is there a **`getXPositionForIndex()`** method already in ACE, or is there a way to write one using the existing methods? This method would take an index (and possibly the scale) for an XYSeries data point, and it would return the "chart space" x-position of that data point. *This is where I'm stuck.*

The whole idea is to touch the screen and find out which of the ten (in this case) data points the user touched closest to.

**Update 2**:

I updated my code just to see what `toRealPoint()` would return. Here is my `OnTouchListener`; as you can see I'm outputting a few different values just to see what I get:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onTouch()");
    Log.i(TAG, "event.x = " + event.getX() + ", event.y = " + event.getY());

    double[] screenPoints = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] {event.getX(), event.getY()}, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "Screen points: " + event.getX() + " = " + screenPoints[0] + ", " + event.getY() + " = " + screenPoints[1]);

    double[] realPoints1 = chart.toRealPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
    Log.i(TAG, "Real points #1: " + event.getX() + " = " + realPoints1[0] + ", " + event.getY() + " = " + realPoints1[1]);

    double[] realPoints2 = chart.toRealPoint((float)screenPoints[0], (float)screenPoints[1]);
    Log.i(TAG, "Real points #2: " + screenPoints[0] + " = " + realPoints2[0] + ", " + screenPoints[1] + " = " + realPoints2[1]);

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, the numbers I get back are not promising:

```
03-27 17:10:18.277: I/MainActivity(1149): onTouch()
03-27 17:10:18.277: I/MainActivity(1149): event.x = 98.19905, event.y = 259.41077
03-27 17:10:18.277: I/MainActivity(1149): Screen points: 98.19905 = 2049.3714971127715, 259.41077 = -Infinity
03-27 17:10:18.287: I/MainActivity(1149): Real points #1: 98.19905 = -Infinity, 259.41077 = 44.807568573847
03-27 17:10:18.297: I/MainActivity(1149): Real points #2: 2049.3714971127715 = -Infinity, -Infinity = Infinity
```

When trying to transform a screen point to a real point using `toRealPoint()`, it always gives me `-Infinity` for the x-position (which is the only one I really care about). I wasn't sure if I was supposed to pass it the "raw" screen points (from the `MotionEvent`) or the "converted" screen points (taken from `toScreenPoint()`), so I tried it with both to see what it would output.

Am I doing something completely wrong? If not, any ideas?

**Update 3**:

I think we (or rather... **I**) may have been over-thinking this way too much. The point provided by `MotionEvent` actually needs no translation; the coordinates it provides is already the right kind, "screen space". What *does* need to be translated is the data point coordinates; they are in "chart space" and in order to compare them to "screen space" you must translate them thusly.

Consider the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onTouch()");
    Log.i(TAG, "event.x = " + event.getX() + ", event.y = " + event.getY());

    for(int i = 0; i < tempSeries.getItemCount(); i++)
    {
        double x = tempSeries.getX(i);
        double y = tempSeries.getY(i);
        double[] screenPoint = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[] { x, y }, 0);

        Log.i(TAG, x + "," + y + " = " + screenPoint[0] + "," + screenPoint[1]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

When the user touches the screen, all I'm doing here is outputting the `MotionEvent` coordinates, and then I'm looping thru every data point in my `XYSeries`. I print out the raw point (which will range from 0.0 to 23.0 as I have 24 data points total). I also print out the translated "screen space" point using the `toScreenPoint()` method. This allows the `MotionEvent` coordinates to be compared with the data point coordinates.

I won't bother posting the long verbose output from this code as it's not really important. What is important is to realize if I touch the screen anywhere vertically around the "8 PM" x-axis (which has an internal data point value of 20 [12 + 8 = 20]), the `MotionEvent` coordinate I receive in my `OnTouchListener` tells me I touched at around x-position 420.0 (+/- 20 or so). Now if I look thru all the translated "screenPoint" values, I find one that is is around 420.0 -- the "8 PM" one!

In short, to translate the user's touch to a data point x-position value you simply need to compare the `MotionEvent` x-position to the `toScreenPoint()`-translated data point x-positions. The `toScreenPoint()` translates the x-positions of the data points to the  same coordinate system that the `MotionEvent` uses (e.g. "screen space"). From there, figuring out which data point the user was closest to when they touched is a trivial matter of looping thru the translated data point x-positions and comparing to the `MotionEvent` x-position. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XYChart` class has such a method:

```
public double[] toScreenPoint(double[] realPoint, int scale)
```

However, in order to use it, you will have to abandon the way you were probably used to create `GraphicalView` instances.

For instance, this:

```
GraphicalView view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer);
```

Will become this:

```
XYChart chart = new LineChart(dataset, renderer);
GraphicalView view = new GraphicalView(context, chart);
```

The benefit of doing this will be that you will have a reference to your `chart` instance, so you can call the method I mentioned.

**Update**: I think the updated question is looking for the reverse method, to transform a screen point into a real point. You can use this method in `XYChart`:

```
public double[] toRealPoint(float screenX, float screenY, int scale)
```

Comment: I've given this more thought and have updated/clarified the question. There are multiple data points in an XYSeries, each added via XYSeries.add(). Each have a zero-based index, assigned based on the order they are added. Is it possible to take this index and get the "chart space" x-position of the data point there? If so, then I can manually do the check and determine which data point the touch is closest to. Any help/tips/guidance you can provide would be so awesome. I'm eventually going to put all this in a tutorial as I'm sure there are others who want to add a "cursor" to their chart. :)

Comment: I hope I got your question right. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes, I believe that is what I'm needing--the reverse method. Thank you so much for your help here, unfortunately I don't think that method will work. I updated the question to show my results.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT! Whoo hoo! You had it right the very first time; the answer was `toScreenPoint()`... I was just simply applying it to the WRONG points. :) I updated the question to reflect that and accepted your answer. Thanks again for all the help with this!

Comment: Thanks for your comment regarding abandoning the use of ChartFactory to setup the graph. I was struggling to get the coordinate conversions to work and didn't realize I had to change the way I load the graph for the conversions to work correctly.